# How to retun a value depending on Two column values in SQL server select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please see below to understand what I want:

```
------------------------------
   Friend       | User 
------------------------------
     2          |  1 
     3          |  2 
     2          |  5
     4          |  2 
------------------------------
```

When I search for value `2`, I want my search result to return related values in `Friend` and `User`, like below:

```
--------------------------
      Friends of 2 
--------------------------
        1   - (from column User ) 
        3   - (from column Friend) 
        5   - (from column user ) 
        4   = (from column friend )
```

I want one column search result like below:

```
--------------------------
      Friends of 2 
--------------------------
        1  
        3   
        5   
        4
```

How can I accomplish this by using a SELECT query in SQL Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT Friend FROM MyTable WHERE User = 2
UNION
SELECT User FROM MyTable WHERE Friend = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case Friend when 2 then User else Friend end
FROM table 
where User = 2 
or Friend = 2;
```

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, not SQL Server

Comment: @gbn: What was particularly MySQL about this? Apart from the missing (now fixed) `end` keyword, the syntax would work in both, no? I would add `DISTINCT`, though, in case the table allowed "symmetric" entries.

Comment: @AndriyM: It was edited within the first few minutes so does not show. It had backticks around table and column names

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Table #MyTable(id int identity,FriendID int,UserID int)

Insert into #MyTable values(2,1),(3,2),(2,5),(4,2)

Declare @SearchUserID int=2

select (Case Friendid when @SearchUserID then userID else FriendID end) as [Friends] from #MyTable where @SearchUserID in(Friendid,UserID)

drop Table #MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option with COALESCE expression

```
SELECT COALESCE(CASE WHEN t.Friend = 2 THEN t.[User] END,
                CASE WHEN t.[User] = 2 THEN t.Friend END) AS [Friends of 2]
FROM dbo.Friend t
WHERE t.Friend = 2 OR t.[User] = 2
```

See exmaple on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ebc9/1)